# Should I provide a citation for atomic masses?

Tags: periodic-table

I am writing my first lab report ever, and the handbook I was given did not say anything in particular about this issue. I will use the atomic masses for my calculations and I am not sure if I should cite the source from which I obtained the data for those figures.

Should I cite periodic tables? If yes, how?

Comment: Usually citing molecular weights is not necessary, especially for a lab report (check the guidelines with your TA though). If you really want to cite anyways, I personally would use *CRC handbook of chemistry and physics*.  There is data for standard atomic weights with ESDs, also tons of other useful information on various constants and properties.

Comment: How would you put the citation markings? For example, right after every calculation using atomic masses?

Comment: I would put a single note in the "Methods and Defnitions" section. But what I'd do is irrelevant. I insist you check the guidelines first as your university might have completely different requirements.

Answer (score 4):

You can’t cite ‘a’ or ‘the periodic table’ because neither are published books. What you can do is state that you took the atomic masses as given by <book> or <source>.

I personally would not do that and I have not yet seen a research article that includes citations for what is considered a well-determined atomic property such as atomic mass or even electronegativity — even though the values for the latter vary greatly depending on source and method used. (Papers that discuss the difference between different definitions being the obvious exception.) Whether you are required to do that depends on what your TA or professor thinks. So go and ask them.